# Scala generation of optional swagger fields

Tags: scala, swagger

Using the swagger editor (http://editor.swagger.io/#/) to generate client scala for definitions of optional fields I would have expected the scala for these fields to be generated as Option[] but that doesn't seem to be the case. Take for example the Pet Store sample json: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-minimal.json

The tag field for Pet in this example is optional but when I generate the client scala code, tag is defined as a String and not Option[String]. How can this be correct?

Comment: What are you using to generate scala code?

Comment: I do it through the website. "File/Import URL" followed by "Generate Client/Scala"

Comment: editor.swagger.io is using generator.swagger.io to generate code and generator.swagger.io is part of the swagger codegen project. please report the issue [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new) so that the team can look into it.